# Section header in slides

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I am writing my dissertation slides and I have a problem. I would like that on top of each slide the name of the section appears but I cannot do it. I tried one code proposed in another post but unfortunately it does not work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you describe where the section should be and how it should look like? How about simply `\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}`?

Comment: In case you need inspiration about how it should look like: https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Comment: @samcarter thank you very much for the link. Now I understood my problem or, at least, I think so. Maybe the problem was the Madrid theme was not able to do what I wanted, so I changed my theme

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments